# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Remote Desktop Acess

Tags: 16.04, remote-desktop, vnc

I have Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on my HP Compaq 6005 SFF and I want to be able to connect to it from a PC, Mac, or another Ubuntu computer. I have installed RealVNC on my computer but I don't know how to get it to run or open up, so until I figure that out I searched on my computer for a remote desktop application and I found one that was installed on the system so I made it to where I can access it without a permissions dialog and I set the password as well, but now how do I access it from my PC or Mac?

Any way that I can fix this?

(I do have access to my router remotely which contains the IP address of my computer but I cannot connect to it through that)
(Teamviewer as well doesn't work as I expect it to, it shows that it's not connected and it won't let me even log in to add it to my contacts and computers.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To connect remotely to a computer system you need these two things

1. **Internet connection**(Broadband connection recommended)
   Remote Desktop Connection software needs to connect via TCP Port 3389
2. **Remote Desktop Connection software**(Team Viewer recommended)
   You can use Team viewer [download it from here]https://www.teamviewer.com/download/linux/.

Comment: Remote desktop connection software should be installed on both systems

Comment: TeamViewer doesn't operate on port 3389, nor does it set up an RDP service.  You have to use their proprietary software to achieve "remote Desktop".  Or use VNC which they tried.